# Comma initialization and Constructors C++ and Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm using Eigen library in C++ and I'm trying to find the determinant of a matrix. I'm getting different results depending on how I initialize the matrices.

**Method I:**

```
MatrixXd a(3, 3);
for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
        a(n,m) = (double) (n + m*m + 2.5)/3;

cout << "Matrix a: " << endl;
cout << a << endl;
cout << "Determinat of matrix a is: " << a.determinant() << endl;
```

This part of the code prints

```
Matrix a:
0.8333333  1.166667  2.166667
1.166667       1.5       2.5
1.5  1.833333  2.833333
Determinat of matrix a is: -7.401487e-17
```

**Method II:**

```
MatrixXd b(3, 3);
b << 0.8333333, 1.166667, 2.166667,
    1.166667, 1.5, 2.5,
    1.5, 1.833333, 2.833333;

cout << b;
cout << endl << "Determinant of matrix b is: " << b.determinant();
```

which prints

```
0.8333333  1.166667  2.166667
1.166667       1.5       2.5
1.5  1.833333  2.833333
Determinant of matrix b is: 2.333331e-07
```

Method I produces the wrong result while Method II gives the right answer. What's going wrong in the first case? (I'm using Visual Studio.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try that calculation by hand, I'm seeing 0 as the exact answer

Comment: You must print floating point numbers with full precision so to make such experiments,in your case: `cout << setprecision(17) << a << endl;`, copy-paste the output to method II (or any other tools), and you'll get same (or rather close enough) determinants.

Answer (score 5):

What you are observing here are **rounding errors** in your calculations. Let me explain it like this:

For a computer, everything is based on the binary number system, i.e. instead of base 10 like we mostly use in our everyday lives, computers calculate with base 2, i.e. only the digits 0 and 1.

This not only applies to integers, but also to real numbers like 0.83333...
But just like it is impossible to write all digits of 0.83333..., your computer cannot store every last digit of the *binary representation* of this number - thus it has to round the result somehow.

Depending on how you initialize it (either by computing `(n + m*m + 2.5)/3` or by reading the value from your comma-initialization), the result might be slightly different in one of the last digits, thus leading to different results.

You can try this out by comparing 0.8333333 with 2.5/3, which will probably return `false`. If you print the numbers, you get the same result, but the internal representation differs ever so slightly.

However you should note that the absolute error itself is quite small (smaller than 0.000001), so you don't need to worry about it at the moment.
If you want exact results, it might be helpful to switch to a rational number type which can represent these values exactly.